# Visual upgrade 2010 -> 2013 fails :(

Tags: 2013, 2010, upgrade

When I follow the wizard steps and do visual experience upgrade of my SharePoint 2010 Solution, which is installed in SharePoint 2013, it ends with the followin error:

> Unfortunately we found some problems   You'll need to fix these before
>   upgrading. We recommend trying out the fixes on a copy of your site
>   collection before you make changes to your production site.
>
> You need to fix the following problem(s) before upgrading:    Missing
>   Site Templates
>
> The following sites are using templates that are not yet supported
>   after upgrade: •http://abc/sites/xyz - EMSMAINSITE#0 Sites that rely
>   on these templates cannot be upgraded at this time, preventing upgrade
>   of this site collection.

I go to my 14\TEMPLATE\1033\XML  folder, copy and paste the missing template file EMSMAINSITE#0 to 15\TEMPLATE\1033\XML

Then SharePoint is able to perform the experience upgrade completelly:

> Upgrade Status
>   Upgrade Completed Successfully 
>   • Status: Upgrade Completed Successfully 
>   • Errors: 0 
>   • Warnings: 0 
>   Letsee the new style

Unfortunately  some of the custom ascx controls are missing. For example I don't see my topnavibar on the sitecollection start page, which is the entry point for my sharepoint solution. 
This ascx control is registered in the .master file:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mycontrol" TagName="TopNavi" src="~/_controltemplates/TopNavi.ascx" %>
```

I can see that my old default .master file isn't the current default .master anymore, but seattle.master is the current master page. And in seattle.master, there isn't such registratin like

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mycontrol" TagName="TopNavi" src="~/_controltemplates/15/TopNavi.ascx" %>
```

When I register my ascx topnavi control in seattle.master and, then something goes wrong and SharePoint says:

Sorry, something went wrong 
Literal content ('&nbsp ') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelTriggerCollection'.

---

I would like to understand why the visual upgrade fails and what is actually happening when i click to "Start Visual Upgrade" and I would like to correct all this, so that my sitecollection with my all custom ascx controls can be used in SharePoint 2013 look.

Edit: The content of the WEBTEMP.EMSMainSite is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Templates xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint">
  <Template Name="EMSMainSite" ID="16000">
    <Configuration ID="0"
                   Title="EMS"
                   Hidden="FALSE"
                   ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/stsprev.gif"
                   Description="Site template for creating EMS main Site"
                   DisplayCategory="EMS">
    </Configuration>
  </Template>
</Templates>
```

Comment: Microsoft removed a couple of site templates moving forward from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. The template you've been using is not available in SP2013 anymore and that's why you initialy can't upgrade your site.
Regarding the error message with the seattle.master I would think that you copied a faulty character and therefor have those issues.

Comment: Thanks,  would this means, that existing installations of my old 2010 solution would not support 2013 visual upgrade, because Microsoft don't supports xxxMAINSITE#0 template in 2013? Is there any Microsoft  Webpage, where I can see which templates are not supported in 2013?

Comment: [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742.aspx#section1) you can find all deprecated features including a couple of site templates

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom controls or site templates installed, you have to take care by yourself for getting them to Support SP2013 (eg being available in the _controltemplates/15 Folder).
MS can only deliver updated controls and templates which they delivered in original SharePoint.

Maybe I´m wrong, but i did met a template called "EMSMAINSITE" so far. Maybe you installed a custom solution which installed that template?

Comment: Hi Leopold, I updated my  question. I think it's a standard Microsoft Template, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I can't find a similar template in my Enterprise farm either.